# What am I doing incorrect in this script?

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime

```
""" Combine both the date and the time with a space and separate the time digits with : and the date digits with /. The date must come before the time."""

from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()

print ('% mm / % dd / % yyyy' '% hh : % mm : ss') (now.month, now.day, now.year now.hour, now.minute, now.second)
```

Ok, so what I am doing is trying to complete a lesson that I have been stuck on from www.codecademy.com and I am scripting in Python v2.7.9. I keep continuously getting the same error as follows:

```
File "python", line 9
    print ('% mm / % dd / % yyyy' '% hh : % mm : ss') (now.month, now.day, now.year now.hour, now.minute, now.second)

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have not been able to figure out what is wrong, and how I fix it. If anyone can help me with this, I will greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is between the sets of brackets.

This is bad syntax for string formatting:

```
print ('% mm / % dd / % yyyy' '% hh : % mm : ss') (now.month, ...
```

You need a percent sign for old-style formating, or `.format` for new style string formatting.

What you are trying to do is something like:

```
print '%d / %d / %d' '%d : %d : %d'%(now.month, now.day, now.year now.hour, now.minute, now.second)
# --- note the percent sign here  -^-
```

Because you are doing a codeacademy course I won't take away the learning, but you can read up more on [Python string formatting to get a final solution](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) on how to best format your strings..

Comment: Does it need a comma between `now.year` and `now.hour`?

Comment: Yes that's what was missing. I actually had missed seeing a forum for the lesson where it told me the problem that most people had and it was the missing comma. Thank you though! I hadn't checked back on here for a few days so sadly I'm just now seeing this. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to do with that weird `print`, but I imagine it's something like:

```
>>> print('%2s / %2s / %4s  %2s : %2s : %2s' % (now.month, now.day, now.year, now.hour, now.minute, now.second))
12 / 23 / 2014  19 : 24 : 38
```

A better approach however would be to do the formatting with the `.strftime` method of `datetime` instances like `now`:

```
>>> print(now.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'))
12/23/2014 19:24:38
```

Note how more concise and readable this is.  And if you insist on those weird extra spaces, you can always add them to the format string you pass to `strftime`:-)

Comment: Thanks but I figured it out now! It was actually missing a comma in between the now.year and now.hour. XD So that was the mistake I made and my friend was waiting for me to figure it out since he knew what was wrong. He just wouldn't tell me lol. Thanks for your help though! I will keep what you said in mind for future references.